# Concatenating nulls in cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I ran across this strange edge case in cypher:

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ return "Foo" + "bar";
+---------------+
| "Foo" + "bar" |
+---------------+
| "Foobar"      |
+---------------+
1 row
8 ms
```

Normal, expected.  Now try concatenating with null:

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ return "Foo" + null;
+--------------+
| "Foo" + null |
+--------------+
| <null>       |
+--------------+
1 row
0 ms
```

Is this the correct behavior?   Why does cypher not return "Foonull" as one would expect, for example in java or most other languages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because according to the [docs](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/cypher-working-with-null.html):

> Most expressions that take `NULL` as input, will produce `NULL`.

Also, I think 'Foonull' just isn't very useful in the context of a Cypher query, but being able to tell whether some value is present, is.

You can use `coalesce` to get the behaviour you want.